# Пропала админ панель в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

После обновления пропадает то, что указано на картинке и я не могу редактировать свой сайт. Скажите пожалуйста как можно исправить подобное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Показ админ бара управляется через хук [show_admin_bar](https://wp-kama.ru/function/show_admin_bar)

Попробуйте вставить в functions.php Вашей темы следующий фрагмент

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_true');
```

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, однако появилась следующая панель (вторая картинка в вопросе), откуда невозможно редактировать сайт. Что делать ?